# How to show objects inside an area?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, representation

I have two different shapefiles:

- point shapefile with many elements
- area shapefile with many regions

I need to create a rule where I need to colour differently the points in some areas, but the areas are in another shapefile

I use QGIS 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an **Intersect** (*Vector* > *Geoprocessing Tools* > *Intersect*) using your point layer as an Input vector layer and your area layer as the Intersect layer:

[image: point and area shapefiles]

[image: Running Intersect]

The result should be a point layer containing attributes from the area shapefile where the point and polygon intersect (`id` is from the point layer; `area` is from the area shapefile).

[image: Attribute table]

You can then create rules using this result layer to colour different points according to area (such as `"area" = 'Bank'`):

[image: Rule-based styling]

Hope this helps!